# How to understand and fix this error? Even the sequence of execution is puzzling

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I'm struggling with two interwoven problems and unfortunately can't easily seperate them for dedicated discussion - so we need to peel off onion layers here...

First: here's an excerpt from a longer pipeline:

```
                    echo "lockfile = ${lockfile}"
                    def cnt = params.COUNTER as Integer
              // get build# of calling job (passed as params.UPSTREAM_URL
                    def tmp = params.UPSTREAM_URL 
              // look for digits enclosed in slashes
                    def pattern = /\/(\d+)\//
                    def matcher = (tmp =~ pattern)
                    matcher.find()
                    def parentJob = matcher.group(1)
                    try {
                        echo "A"
                        echo "B"
                        lockfile = lockfile + '.' + parentJob
                        echo "C, cnt=${cnt}, lf=${lockfile}"
                        sleep 10 * cnt
                        echo "D"
                        timeout(time: citaConfig.timeoutMinutes, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                            while (checkIfExists(lockfile + '.*')) {
                                while (checkIfExists(lockfile + '.*')) {
                                    sleep 30  // wait until lockfile is removed
                                }
                                sleep 10 * cnt // add a final wait to avoid overlaps
                            }
                        }
                        if (checkIfExists(lockfile)) {
                            error("timeout waiting for release of lockfile \"${lockfile}\"")
                        }
                        sh "echo '${BUILD_URL}' > ${lockfile}.${BUILD_NUMBER} "
                    } catch(error) {
                        echo "C5  - caught ${error}"
                        echo error.getMessage()
                    }
```

The log for this portion of the code shows:

```
[Pipeline] echo
lockfile = /foo/goo.txt
[Pipeline] echo
A
[Pipeline] echo
B
[Pipeline] echo
C, cnt=1, lf=/foo/goo.txt.144
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] echo
C5  - caught java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
[Pipeline] echo
java.util.regex.Matcher
[Pipeline] }
```

1. What's the issue with the regex matcher?
2. I'm mystified as to why the system processed output "`C`", goes on and `sleep`s and then throws the error - why doesn't it get to `echo "D"` - and how could I find out where exactly things are getting off track (if obviously this poor man's approach doesn't do it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by avoiding regex altogether.

```
                 def tmp = params.UPSTREAM_URL 
                 def parentJob = null
                 def segments = tmp.split("/")
                 for (segment in segments) {
                     if (segment.isNumber()) {
                         parentJob = segment
                         break
                     }
                 }
                 if (parentJob == null) {
                     error ('Could not determine parent job!')
                 }
```

(BTW, this snippet was suggested by Bing Chat!)

But ofc I would have felt better with an answer to the original question and will happily accept any answer explaining that...